# Kafka Consumer skipping messages on restart

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a Kafka cluster running and when restarting a application (consumer) it skips some messages that were pushed to the topic while the application beeing down.

When the application is up I can see that it read message with offset `100`, and then pushes offset `101` to `__consumer_offsets`. Then while the application is down messages with offsets `101, 102 and 103` are pushed to the topic. After restart of the application it reads `101` and sets it offset to `104`, thus, skipping `102 and 103`.

This is my config:

```
config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaCluster);
config.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, my-consumer);
config.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
config.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, deserializer);
```

Comment: Yes the internal topic.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the available information, it doesn't look like your consumer is skipping any messages.

After consuming the message with offset `100`, the internal topic `__consumer_offsets` stores the offset `101` for this consumer. The offset `101` is the *next* offset the consumer will read on that topic.

After the restart, and having 3 more messages in the topic, the consumer starts processing offset `101` and should also process the other messages subsequently. However, based on your commit strategy it reports back to the internal topic `__consumer_offsets` that the next message to be read has offset `104`. It will not specifically state 101, 102 and 103 as all messages are polled at once.